# "bin\Debug\Daemon.exe.manifest;bin\Release\Daemon.exe.manifest" is an invalid value for the "InputManifest" parameter of the * task

Tags: c#

Error :

> ```
> Error 1   "bin\Debug\Daemon.exe.manifest;bin\Release\Daemon.exe.manifest"
> ```
>
> is an invalid value for the
>   "InputManifest" parameter of the
>   "GenerateApplicationManifest" task.
>   Multiple items cannot be passed into a
>   parameter of type
>   "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem".    Daemon

Comment: can you provide more specifics about the process that's generating it?  It's pretty clearly a build-related error, is it from MSBuild, is it part of a ClickOnce build?  Do you have any supporting scripts, etc, that you can provider?

Comment: Yes it is a buid error. It is nor a part of ClickOnce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got an invalid setting in the msbuild file. I guess would be that the GenerateApplicationManifest task expects a valid file name for the input manifest parameter.

Comment: @jcmcbeth yes, but there isn't a question to answer!

Comment: how is this the accepted answer doesn't even tell you how to correct....?

Answer (score 42):

I solved this bug by removing unselecting the "Enable clickonce security settings" in security settings of the project properties.

Comment: Thanks Anuya. I was facing the same problem and solved now.

But getting another new error: 

Could not find file 'bin\Debug\RadControlsWinFormsSIS.xml'. RadControlsWinFormsSIS

Comment: Funny enough, I have solved the same problem by *enabling* the ClickOnce security settings...

Comment: Now I can't disable this setting. It turns on automatically when I'm trying to publish my app.

Comment: Up-voted as it did solve the problem but any idea why? My app has been working for years and I don't know of a change that was made that may have caused this to start happening or that is related to click once security settings.

Answer (score 11):

Exceelent, this worked for me also. I started getting the problem -->

is an invalid value for the "InputManifest" parameter of the "GenerateApplicationManifest" task. Multiple items cannot be passed into a parameter of type "Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITaskItem

When I added the whole solution including resource folder bin obj etc into SourceSafe.

Switching the "Enable ClickOnce Security Setting" Off Solve the issue imediately

Thanks Guys

Duncan Lawrence